# cannot manipulate value returned from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, promise

I use the following code to call a database query (Node.js).  The code seems operative in the sense that I get data output returned to my calling function.  The problem is that I seem unable to manipulate this data...I have no idea what the problem is.

database script ('queries.js'):

```
function getFinals() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results) => {
   if (error) {
   reject(new Error('Ooops, something broke!'));
   } else {
   resolve(results.rows);
   }
  })  //pool.query

 }); 
}
```

my 'main' script:

```
const db = require('./routes/queries');

app.get('/lookup', function (req, res) {

 db.getFinals()
 .then(function(value) {
 console.log('Async success!', value);
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
 console.log('Caught an error!', err);
 });

});
```

My data from the database call is displayed from the 'value' in the console.log...however I cannot do anything with this variable data.  I wish to run a loop, for example:

```
for (_count = 0; _count < (value.length - 1); _count++) {
console.log("count...!" + _count);
}
```

However nothing happens, the loop does not execute.  It seems the 'value' is undefined...why...???  How can I use my data that is returned from the (seemingly) functional database call...???   This is extremely frustrating...any suggestions appreciated.

The full calling function with the loop inclusive:

```
app.get('/lookup', function (req, res) {

db.getFinals()
  .then(function(value) {
  console.log('Async success!', value);

   for (_count = 0; _count < (value.length - 1); _count++) {
   console.log("count...!" + _count);
   }

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Caught an error!', err);
  });

});
```

My output from the console.log is like so:

```
Async success! [ { name: 'administration',
cred: 'peace',
status: 'active',
login: '2090',
logout: 'na',
service: 'both',
lucky: 'na',
picture: null,
picturex: null,
vod: null,
vodx: null,
legacy: 'na' } ]
```

which is equal to what it should display.  The other strange thing is that this prints twice...despite that there is only 1 record in the database table...not sure if that is an issue or normal behaviour of a promise call...?

Comment: ` It seems the 'value' is undefined` - if it were undefined you'd get an error - is your `for` loop inside the `.then` where `value` is defined?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes it is.  I edited the post to include the code as within the '.then'...I do not see "count...!" in my console as I should.  Is my syntax correct for the 'promise'...?  I am not experienced in their usage.

Comment: What value gets output here: `console.log('Async success!', value);`

Comment: Hello, I posted the output I see in my console.  It seems correct, with the "Async success!" message followed by the database output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting data in the above, the issue is your loop: array's are zero-based and you are doing `_count < (result.length - 1)` which means you won't loop over the last record. In your case, there is only one row so it won't loop.

Correct syntax would be: `i < result.length`

See the demo:

```js
const result = [ { name: 'administration',
cred: 'peace',
status: 'active',
login: '2090',
logout: 'na',
service: 'both',
lucky: 'na',
picture: null,
picturex: null,
vod: null,
vodx: null,
legacy: 'na' } ];

for (_count = 0; _count < (result.length - 1); _count++) {
  console.log(`existing loop: name is ${result[i].name}`);
}

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(`correct loop: name is ${result[i].name}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice catch...I changed my loop to be "_count <= (value.length - 1)" ...and I can now see the "count...!" in the console.  Just making 'less than OR equal to' made the difference.  Sorry about that error I copied the loop text from another function and didn't think to adjust for only 1 record in the results.  Thanks again.

Comment: No, prob. Good luck with the rest of it.

Comment: At least I know my promise code seems to be using correct syntax, I'm new to using promises to call database functionality...thanks again.